# sql server coalesce get first not null date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2008.
I was wondering if this is the best code to get the first not null date:

```
    select actualdate = coalesce((select date1 from table1), (select date2 from table2))
```

Comment: You can use `ISNULL`, `COALESCE`, or filter all records where `date1` IS NOT NULL and taking the TOP 1 based on some sort of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IsNull` in this context.

---

`Coalesce` should be used when you have more then one column to get `Not Null` value.

### Example

```
select ISNULL((select top 1 OBJECT_ID from sys.objects), 0)
go
select coalesce((select top 1 OBJECT_ID from sys.objects), 0)
```

**[Click here to see the SQL Profiler Read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuuZB.png)**

---

You are missing `Top` statement in the query otherwise you can face following error..

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: A big advantage of COALESCE over ISNULL is portability. The former is ANSI SQL, the latter is SQL Server dialect.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. But, whenever I scan my queries in Sql-Profiler, `Coalesce` use more reads and more `Duration`...Sorry, don;t have any sample query at the moment.

Comment: Downvoted because the first two points you made don't actually answer any question.  If you back up your comment with proof, I'll remove it.

Comment: @Norla - are you available for discussion now ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can join the two tables using some common id the you can use this below query.

```
select @actualdate = CASE WHEN t1.date1 is null then t2.date else t1.date end
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

if you dont have any common ids between these 2 tables then try to use CTEs with row_number() to join the 2 tables.